# Import bluebird on quasar

Tags: vue.js, bluebird, quasar-framework

I am using [bluebird.js](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) and Quasar Framework. I would like to use it globally and previously configure it like

```js
import { Promise } from 'bluebird';

Promise.config({
    cancellation: true });
```

But I'm not sure where to place it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is what [Boot files](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files) were supposed for.

```js
// src/boot/promise.js
export default () => {
  import { Promise } from 'bluebird';

  Promise.config({ cancellation: true });
}
```

```js
// quasar.conf.js
{
  boot: [ 'promise' ]
}
```